# TTLock API | errmsg: date must be current time, in 5 minutes

Tags: python, http, request, http-post

I had a problem when dealing with TTLock APIs. When I send a POST request, the date is requested in milliseconds, but when I enter the current time value, I get this message:

> "date must be current time, in 5 minutes".

Send POST request to TTLock API, to get a response, but it always sends me an error message. All the problem with the value of 'Date' parameter, what should I do?

The value which I write is like "1689420010".

In TTLock documents the description of 'date' parameter is "Current time (timestamp in millisecond)"

TTLock Documents: https://euopen.ttlock.com/document/doc?urlName=cloud%2Flock%2FlistEn.html

I tried in many ways, but I couldn't solve this problem.
Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem. Just convert timestamp in milliseconds
After that everything work for me.